# Can I run C#(.cs)file in code::Blocks

Tags: c#, ubuntu, codeblocks

I have a form2.cs file and I installed code::Blocks in Ubuntu 10.04. how can I run this file using code::Blocks? Is it possible to run the code by configuring the code::Blocks?

Comment: You should probably use [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks is primarily a **C++** IDE and from searching online it **doesn't** look like one of the other languages it supports is C#. People are pointing to [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) as a similar alternative.

Comment: sharpDevelop is for windows and i.e not for the Linux

Comment: Updated to link to MonoDevelop.